# Ruby: line.start_with? doesn't read criteria variable correctly

Tags: ruby

I have the following snippet:

```
buffer = ""
sourceFile = File.read("#{options[:source]}")
destFile = File.open("#{options[:dest]}", "w+")

criteria = ""
if (options[:ora]) then 
    criteria += "\"SELECT\", \"UPDATE\""
    puts criteria
end

sourceFile.each_line do |line|
    if (line.start_with?("#{criteria}")) then 
        buffer << line
        buffer << "\n\n"
    end
end

File.write("#{options[:dest]}", buffer)
```

This doesn't work though -- the destination file is empty. However, if I hardcode `if (line.start_with?("UPDATE", "SELECT")) then`, it works fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the string '"SELECT", "UPDATE"' to function, instead you should pass strings separately(you can use lists and parameter expension if you generate those dynamically):

```
criteria = ["SELECT", "UPDATE"]
...
line.start_with?(*criteria)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
buffer = ""
sourceFile = File.read("#{options[:source]}")
destFile = File.open("#{options[:dest]}", "w+")

criteria = ""
if (options[:ora]) then 
  criteria += %w(SELECT UPDATE)
  puts criteria
end

sourceFile.each_line do |line|
  if (line.start_with?(*criteria)) then 
    buffer << line
    buffer << "\n\n"
  end
end

File.write("#{options[:dest]}", buffer)
```